# JQuery reload page after all checkbox filters set - get correct url

Tags: jquery, radio-button, shopify, liquid

In shopify's liquid, I create different groups of radio buttons in a loop, each group has the same class, to allow only one selection of one radio button in each group. I don't want immediate reload of my page. Insted, after all selections made, you should click on a button to reload the page with all filters set.

If you click on a radio button, an url is created with that button, that I get as an alert (just for debugging). If you click on the next button, there is a new url with the alert. The url looks like .../tag1, the next url like .../tag2. In liquid,  link_to_remove_tag creates also a link with all filter tags set, but I don't know how to collect all the tags of the filters set.

If I click on the "apply filters" button, I need to check all activated buttons  and create the new url with liquid, I gues with {{ tagName | link_to_remove_tag: tag }}, but I don't know how. At the moment the JQuery for the "apply button" is not working at all. I'd be incredibly happy about some help.

[screenshot of my radio buttons with apply button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGZxK.png)

```
    {% for cheese in cheeses %}
      {% assign ghosttown = cheese %}
      {% for tag in tags %}
          {% if tag contains cheese %}
             <div class="sortby-dropdown-div flex-filter">
                {% include 'sortby-dropdown' %}
                  <a href="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">
                    <h2 class="sidebar-h3 flex-filter">Alle Filter zurücksetzen</h2>
                  </a>
                    <h2 class="apply-filter-btn flex-filter">Filter anwenden</h2>
              </div>
            <ul class="filterlist flex-filter">
            {% if current_tags contains tag %} 
                 <li class="sidebarfilters sidebar-current">
                   <label class="sidebar-checkboxlabel">
                     <input  class="filter_checkbox radio-btn" id="checked" type="radio" checked onClick="" name= {{ ghosttown }}>         
                       {{ tagName | link_to_remove_tag: tag }}
                   </label>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li  class="sidebarfilters">
                  <label class="sidebar-checkboxlabel">
                    <input  class="filter_checkbox radio-btn" id="unchecked" type="radio" onClick=""  name= {{ ghosttown }}>
                    {{ tagName | link_to_add_tag: tag }}
                  </label>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
            </ul>
          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    
    
    
    $('.filter_checkbox').off().change( function(){
    var newURL = $(this).nextAll('a').attr('href');
      alert(newURL);
    });
    
    $('.apply-filter-btn').off().click( function() {
      var newURL = $(this).nextAll('a').attr('href');
      alert(newURL);
      window.location.href = newURL;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could remove your checkbox `change` handler and rely solely on the Apply button `click` handler instead. Within the click handler you can use jQuery to fetch all of the checked filters and form an appended string of the filters values.

To do this you will first need to attach the `{{ tag }}` data to the checkbox inputs as the value:

```
<input class="filter_checkbox radio-btn" type="radio" value="{{ tag }}">
```

Next you can re-write the "Apply" button handler like so:

```
$('.apply-filter-btn').click( function() {
  var allFilters = '';
  var $activeFilters = $('.filter_checkbox:checked');
  var activeFiltersCount = $activeFilters.length;
  var lastActiveFilterIndex = activeFiltersCount - 1;
  $activeFilters.each(function (index) {
    var filterValue = $(this).val(); // the tag
    allFilters += filterValue; // append the tag to our filters
    // To use multiple filters at once you must separate them with a + (plus)
    if (index !== lastActiveFilterIndex) {
      allFilters += '+';
    }
  });

  // Append filters to the base URL and redirect the user to the new URL
  var newUrl = window.location.pathname + '/' + allFilters;
  window.location = newUrl;
});
```